# Using SignalR to find out if someone pushed a button on another website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, signalr

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to use SignalR and be notified (in real-time) if a visitor has pushed a button on another site (different domain). First off, is SignalR the best way of doing this? Second, I have all the Javascript logic to find out if the visitor has actually clicked the button of interest but don't know how to relay that message to my server (where the real-time tracker will be).

Second, There is no way of knowing what kind of technology (php, asp.net, regular html) will be running on the other end of the where the signal will be generated, will this be a problem?

Lastly, the biggest reason why I would like to use SignalR (other than to start using it and learn it :) ) is so that I can have near real-time reporting of the activity on the dashboard. If there is a better solution (other than regular javascript polling and updating) by all means please let me know.

I guess by these questions you can easily find out that I'm a newbee in the SignalR world and would need as much help as possible as this is going to be my first project in this field.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You don't need to use HTML for formatting in your questions.  We use Markdown.  [See the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SignalR self-hosting server for this. [self host example](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host)  I use this to have multiple clients to access the same Hubs and thus receive notifications from other clients/sites.

Here is an example of what my self hosted main looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using SignalR.Hosting.Self;

namespace SelfHostedSignalr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
            Debug.AutoFlush = true;

            string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
            var server = new Server(url);

            server.MapHubs();
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo ki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the example of the Self Hosted Sample that comes with the source code to work but I keep getting the following    Error 2 Could not load type 'SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.Samples.Global'. C:\Users\Hiva\Downloads\SignalR-SignalR-0.5.0-204-g6ca5840\SignalR-SignalR-6ca5840\samples\SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.Samples\Global.asax 1

Comment: Either I'm not looking at the right place or this project is very poorly documented

Comment: I have added what my self hosted server main function looks like.  Basically I am only using it to serve up hubs, so I dropped everything else.  I would look at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs for how to call this self hosted server from javascript (aka any number of web sites)  Signalr has been updated in version .5.1 to have better cross domain support so you shouldn't have to worry about that because signalr takes care of it for you.